# 'Feature' and 'Scenario' aliases from Capybara throw an 'undefined method' error when used with RSpec

Tags: rspec, capybara

It looks like those aliases are not loaded properly. I'm using Rails 3.X, rspec 2.8 and capybara 1.1.2 to write some integration tests. 
I think that my installation of Capybara is successful as it all works with the standard 'describe' and 'it' tags, but 'feature' and 'scenario' aliases from Capybara throw an 'undefined method' error.

I don't see anything in the documentation mentioning more configuration:
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara
I have simply added the 'require capybara/rspec' in my spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems like you can't combine describe/it with feature/scenario syntax. I was getting the same error when I nested a `scenario` block inside a `describe` block. Once I replaced the `describe` with `feature`, the test ran. One gotcha: It also does not seem to like nested `feature` blocks, which I guess makes sense in the context of acceptance testing.

```
describe "some feature" do  # <== BAD
  scenario "some scenario" do
    #spec code here
  end
end

feature "some feature" do  # <== GOOD
  scenario "some scenario" do
    #spec code here
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**
I dug into Capybara's source code, and `before` and `it` don't get aliased by `background` and `scenario` [unless the `describe` block gets created with `capybara_feature => true`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec/features.rb#L22) which happens when you [create the block with `feature`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec/features.rb#L14) instead of `describe`.

Comment: I get here because I was nesting "scenario" blocks to add context to the tests and I just discovered that you have the "context" block to do this!